# How to submit web performance testing results with WebDriver to WebPageTest?

Tags: python, performance, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, webpagetest

I want to automate performance testing of web app with Selenium Webdriver in Python.

I followed the suggested solution at the GTAC talk [Web Performance Testing with WebDriver](https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/1p24ZsElU8UKylXWrpJ5DuoQkeUhS_phSeZz08BoTiAM/pub?start=false&loop=false&delayms=3000#slide=id.gd3000319_0191)

Here is [the example of the code](https://gist.github.com/klepikov/5457750) in Java and Python.
But in Python example only part of getting logs form Dev tools is described.
And the part of submitting logs to WebPageTest is provided only in Java.

I got the performance logs from Chrome Dev tools in JSON format. Here is a part:

```
{
    "params":
    {
        "initiator": {"type": "other"},
        "documentURL": "https://stackoverflow.com/",
        "timestamp": 43210.132828,
        "request": {
            "mixedContentType": "none",
            "headers": {
                "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/54.0.2840.100 Safari/537.36",
                "Upgrade-Insecure-Requests": "1"
            },
            "url": "https://stackoverflow.com/",
            "initialPriority": "VeryHigh",
            "method": "GET"
        },
        "frameId": "29134.1",
        "requestId": "29134.1",
        "loaderId": "29134.1",
        "type": "Document",
        "wallTime": 1479142661.979178
    },
    "method": "Network.requestWillBeSent"
}
```

And now I am unable to submit results to webpagetest.org.

Does anyone has experience with submitting performance test results from Selenium WD Python to WebPageTest?